# REGEXEXTRACT to extract values and sum up a series of numbers

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

In a Google spreadsheet, I have a row of random text and numbers, such as:

`K,,,1-3,,K,RBI-1,RBI-4`

I want to get all occurrences of `RBI-[1-4]` and sum the values for each `RBI-[1-4]`. I came up with the following which gets me an array of what I want:

`=ARRAYFORMULA((RIGHT(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:H1,"RBI-[1-4]"),0))))`

Produces:
`0,0,0,0,0,0,1,4`

But now when I want to sum the results I get zero.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM((RIGHT(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:H1,"RBI-[1-4]"),0)))))`

Produces
`0`

Any suggestions where I am going south?

Answer (score 1):

## Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(value((RIGHT(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:H1,"RBI-[1-4]"),0))))))
```

## Explanation

REGEXTRACT returns values as TEXT, so before summing them, we should convert them to numbers.

There are several ways to do this. The above formula use VALUE function but we could also use `+0`, `*1`, among other methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to remove the `RIGHT` portion of the formula you'll see that the results are actually 0,0,0,0,0,0,RBI-1,RBI-4. Also, `REGEXEXTRACT`returns a text. We need turn the results into numbers. Adding `VALUE` to the formula will do that for us.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:H1,"RBI-[0-9]+"),"[0-9]+")),0))
```

If you just want the result without the zeros just wrap it all in `SUM`.

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:H1,"RBI-[0-9]+"),"[0-9]+")),0)))
```

I'm sure there's a more eloquent way of doing this, but it works.